# Can month and day values in a PHP and MYSQL DATE variable be 0 or null?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm in the planning stages of creating a historical database. I will be using PHP, MYSQL and JavaScript for the website.

Often someone will know what year a person was born or picture was taken, but not the month or the day.

Is it possible for a PHP DATE variable and MYSQL DATE to be:
1920-00-00 or 1845-12-00 ?

If not, unless someone has a better idea, I'll have to create a column for year, another column for month, and yet another for day then do a bunch of value checking and combining.

Thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Not using DATE. You can use VARCHAR tho. But it will be harder to get values in order by date

Comment: That's a good idea Phiter.  Based on the answer below that's what I'll do.

Comment: you can use date format  to display only the month and date. http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php. I suggest you save the date properly (coz you REALLY need this data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need exakt dates for using date in mysql, so you probably have to bite down and filter everything for validating and then some code to combine it.